# (Django REST Framework) Basic authentication doesn't work when app is served through NGINX

Tags: django, authentication, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I'm building an API and I finally got it working to serve it through Gunicorn and NGINX. Nginx proxies incoming requests to a socket binded to Gunicorn. The problem is this:

When I try to access the API directly by running the 'gunicorn command or by using the builtin 'runserver' command from Django, and having configured Django REST Framework's BasicAuthentication as the default authentication class in the settings.py-file, everything works fine. Each time I try to access an endpoint, it asks me for a valid username/password-combo, just like you would expect.

However, when I try to access the API through NGINX, which has a proxy_pass configured to the unix socket which Gunicorn is bound to, BasicAuthentication doesn't work anymore. All requests are granted, without providing a username and password.

I know basic authentication should be avoided, but it's a requirement for a project I'm working on. Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve this?

**settings.py:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
),
}
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
http {
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


upstream *** {

    server unix:/***/***/***/***/***/***/***.sock
    fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

server_name     <server-name>;

    satisfy         all;

    allow           <IP-address>
    deny            all;


    # location = /favicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off;}

    location /static/ {
       autoindex on;
       alias ../static/;
    }

location / {
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_pass http://<upstream>;
    }


listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/***/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/***/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

}

Comment: do you get any kind of error?

Comment: @SırrıKırımlıoğlu Nope, I'm getting a 200 as a response. Also checked the error log of NGINX, but nothing to see there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to solve it myself. I don't know what the cause was because I also had the same problem before using Gunicorn, but restarting it solved it somehow.